# How do I create my docker image from a forked GITHUB repo?

Tags: docker, grafana

I forked Grafana into my repo and I made some changes to it, I want to test this in docker.

How do I build this as a docker image?

PS: Am new to this.

Thank you

Comment: Check their [Dockerfile](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/blob/master/Dockerfile) if it fits and use `docker build -t my-grafana .` to build the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Grafana](https://github.com/grafana/grafana) has a Dockerfile, so you can build a Docker image using that file.

In your forked directory, run the following to build the image.

```
docker build --tag grafana .
```

This will create a Docker image named `grafana` with your changes.

Then follow [Grafana's instructions](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/installation/docker/#run-grafana) on running from a Docker image:

```
docker run -d -p 3000:3000 --name grafana-dev grafana
```

and open `localhost:3000` in a browser.

You might consider looking at the documentation for [`docker run`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/) and [`docker build`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/).

Comment: I wanted to change the name of the forked directory,
So I am gonna try this:

docker build --rm -f "Dockerfile" -t xyz:latest 

Hope this works.

Comment: That should be fine. If this answered your question, please feel free to select the green arrow to accept it.